# How to read Error Reports

Tags: android, eclipse, parse-platform

What does this mean?
I am new to coding and mostly self taught but I don't know how to read this and if the error is PARSE related I don't know how to fix it I have Spent Hours pouring over the code for the PARSE(Copied directly from PARSE website).

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.RuntimeException: applicationContext is null. You must call Parse.initialize(context, applicationId, clientKey) before using the Parse library.
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2675)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:175)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1384)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: applicationContext is null. You must call Parse.initialize(context, applicationId, clientKey) before using the Parse library.
at com.parse.Parse.checkContext(Parse.java:557)
at com.parse.Parse.getApplicationContext(Parse.java:165)
at com.parse.ManifestInfo.getContext(ManifestInfo.java:221)
at com.parse.ManifestInfo.getPackageManager(ManifestInfo.java:229)
at com.parse.ManifestInfo.getPackageInfo(ManifestInfo.java:240)
at com.parse.ManifestInfo.deviceSupportsGcm(ManifestInfo.java:325)
at com.parse.ManifestInfo.getPushType(ManifestInfo.java:109)
at com.parse.PushService.startServiceIfRequired(PushService.java:150)
at com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(ParseBroadcastReceiver.java:19)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2660)
```

Answer (score 0):

It tells you exactly what to do.  "You must call Parse.initialize(context, applicationId, clientKey) before using the Parse library."